# How to remove CSS files if the page being rendered is a front page in a theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to remove default Drupal CSS files if it is a front page in Drupal 7 theme.

Following is the code (got from http://www.grahamgilchrist.com/blog/25) that I am trying to put in the template.php for barktik1 theme. How do I check if rendering page is a front page or not? Only $css variable is passed as an argument to the theme_css_alter() function while for other *process* functions $variables is passed from which it is easy to determine if it is a front page or not.

```
function bartik1_css_alter(&$css) { 

//do something to check if it is a front page
if ($is_front){
    //make a list of module css to remove 
    $css_to_remove = array(); 
    $css_to_remove[] = drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.base.css'; 
    $css_to_remove[] = drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.menus.css'; 

    // now we can remove the contribs from the array 
    foreach ($css_to_remove as $index => $css_file) { 
      unset($css[$css_file]); 
    } 
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`drupal_is_front_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7).

Answer (score 0):

In both Drupal 7 and 8 you have     `hook_css_alter` for altering  CSS files before  output on the page.

If you want to remove some default css file from your Drupal 7 home page you can go with:

```
function YOUR_THEME_css_alter(&$css) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page() == TRUE  )  {
    unset($css['/'.drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME').'/css/removeme.css'] );
  }
}
```